# Why do I get this error, and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, typeerror

Here is my code:

```
list1 = ['monkey', 'banana', 'pizza']
list2 = []

for x in list1:
    input = input(f"Do you want to add {x} to list 2? [y/n] ")
    if input == "y" or input == "Y":
        list2.append(x)
    if input == "n" or input == "N":
        continue

print(list2)
```

I want to go through list1 and ask if each thing should be added to list2, but I get this error:

```
example.py 5 <module>
input = input(f"Do you want to add {x} to list 2? [y/n] ")

TypeError:
'str' object is not callable
```

The error happens when I give a input. Why do I get this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: you shouldn't redefine the builtin ```input```, there's also no point in the 2nd ```if``` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning input, a default function in Python. You are then trying to call this function, but it has been reassigned to a string, causing your error. This is not recommended, and to mitigate this issue choose another variable name.

You can also simplify your code by using `str.lower()`. Along with this, the second if condition is not needed.

```py
list1 = ['monkey', 'banana', 'pizza']
list2 = []

for x in list1:
    user_input = input(f"Do you want to add {x} to list 2? [y/n]")
    if user_input.lower() == "y":
        list2.append(x)

print(list2)
```

Comment: there's no point in having the second ```if``` statement if you just ```continue```

Comment: @Nin17 updated answer

Answer (score 0):

On the second iteration of your list, you are trying to use the function "input".

But on the first iteration of your list, you've already assigned a string to input.

So during your second iteration, "input" no longer gives you the function, it gives you the string and you are trying to "call" it using the parens()